# Are there disadvantages to including many options in a responsive <img>'s srcset?

Tags: html, lazy-loading, responsive, responsive-images, srcset

A project I'm currently working on needs responsive, lazy-loaded images with particularly flexible sizing: any given component may be rendered at the full width of the screen or down to 25% of it depending on other contextual elements, and we're trying to build for all screen sizes.

We're using [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) for our lazy-loading, partly because of its awesome `data-sizes="auto"` attribute that sets the `<img>` tag's `sizes` attribute to its exact pixel width before initiating lazy-loading.

The only real issue I'm running into is **what to include as the `srcset`**: we'd like them to be uniform across the site (so we can instruct the CMS to just auto-generate the same sizes for any uploaded image).

I'm tempted to say something like "here are the 5 most common sizes images will be rendered; include all of these and 2x all of these for high-resolution devices". However, this means including 10 sources for each file.

**Are there any disadvantages to including lots of (more than 3-5) sources in a single `<img>`'s `srcset`?**

The only ones I can think of (and that I've found searching for this elsewhere on the internet) are (1) server-side things (e.g. extra processing, more files to store) and (2) in the rare case where a user starts with a small window and resizes smoothly to a large window, the browser could download many copies of the same image. I'm not really worried about either of these cases.

Comment: (1) Extra processing is performed once only (per image), so it is not a big problem, don't worry if you have enough free disk space; (2) Very rare case.

Comment: @DenisRyabov Yeah, those are in line with what I was thinking as well. Do you know/can you think of any other possible disadvantages? I'm not planning on doing something extreme (like a new image for every 10px or something) but it'd be nice to have like 10 sources included if it's not going to cause issues!

Comment: There is no significant disadvantages. I would prefer instant internet and unlimited memory to load full resolution images, but the speed of light is finite, the data channel is shared among several clients, etc. The only issue I know is that "Save as" menu item in browsers saves current image instead of display a submenu to choose which one to save. But this kind of issues should be solved by browsers, moreover there is the same issue with picture elements (and it seems there is no popular browser that is able to save video and audio elements at all).